# Memoization in Java

Tags: c#, java, performance, function, memoization

Ok so in C# I could write:

```
public class Memorizer<K,TRes>
{
    private Dictionary<K,TRes> _mem;
    private Func<K,TRes> _function

    public Memorizer (Func<K,TRes> function)
    {
        _function = function;
        _mem= new Dictionary<K,TRes>();
    }

    public TRes Call(K arg)
    {
        if (mem.ContainsKey(arg)
        {
            return _mem[arg];
        }
        else
        {
            TRes ret=_function(arg);
            _mem[arg] = ret;
            return ret;
        }
    }
}
```

Which could be made use of for obvious gains:

```
public class FactorialCalculator()
{
    private Memorizer<ushort, ulong> _memorizedFactorial;
    public FactorialCalculator()
    {
        _memorizedFactorial = new Memorizer<ushort, ulong> (innerFactorial);
    }

    private ulong innerFactorial(ushort x)
    {
        return (x=0) ? 1 : x*Factorial(x-1)
    }

    public ulong factorial(ushort x)
    {
        _memorizedFactorial.Call(x);
    }

}
```

I'm sure it could be made more general and elegant.
And I know I'll have overflow exceptions if x>20. 
(And I may have typecast errors in there too)
BUt hopefully I made my point: i can create a class that can furful the needs for memoisation of pure mathematical functions  (I.e. deterministic, side-effect free functions)
and get wonderful performance gains.

How can I accomplish a similar thing in Java?

Comment: I believe these are called "memoizer", not "memorizer".

Comment: Also it's *Dictionary*, not *Dictionairy* in the *"new Dictionairy"* line.

Comment: Also, it's more efficient to compute factorial based on its prime factorization.  For each prime p <= n, the number of times it appears as a factor of n! is something like sum(i * floor(n / pow(p, i))) for natural numbers i.

Comment: @Mike, It was just an example. To demonstarate a point.

Comment: OP, here's a Java implementation that is very near the one you outline: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77384428/501113

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pass functions as data types in java. To fix this, use an interface.

```
public interface ReturnFunction<K, V> {
    public V getValue(K k);
}
```

Now you can set innerFactorial to a data type.

```
public ReturnFunction<Short, Long> innerFactorial = new ReturnFunction<Short, Long>(){
    public Long getValue(Short x){
        return (x=0) ? 1 : x*Factorial(x-1);
    }
};
```

This lets you pass `innerFactorial` as a data type:

```
_memoizedFactorial = new Memorizer<Short, Long> (innerFactorial);
```

And to call the function you write this:

```
long someLong = _memoizedFactorial.getValue(someShort);
```

Also, in Java don't capitalize field or method names. It's not standard and makes the code harder to read.

Comment: Check out Guava's Function interface. No need to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: @John B Thanx never heard of it before but it's nice.

Comment: For theorical purposes, and because introducting a extra libnray for 3 lines of code is frowned upon. There is nothing wrong with reinventing the wheel.

Comment: What if I had multiple functions i wanted to memorise in one class?
Would i have to wrap each in an inner class implimenting function? or is there a more elegant way?

Comment: `and because introducting a extra libnray for 3 lines of code is frowned upon. There is nothing wrong with reinventing the wheel.` I couldn't disagree more.

Comment: `What if I had multiple functions i wanted to memorise in one class? Would i have to wrap each in an inner class implimenting function?` You would need different cache's for each different memorization

Comment: @John: Sorry there want an extra full stop there:
"For *theorical purposes*, and ..., there is nothing wrong with reinventing the wheel."
Indeed for Practial purposes I would use Guava's cache package, as John B suggested

Comment: Oh I see.  Yea it would be useless to use guava when learning how to write a memorizer :)

Comment: @Leo I get it we are implementing innerFactorial as an annonomous inner class, right?

Answer (score 3):

In Java 8 you can use the computeIfAbsent to achieve memoization :

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.function.Function;

public class FactorialCalculator {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Function<Integer, Long> factorialFunction = x -> {
        System.out.println("Calculating factorial for " + x);
        long fact = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
            fact *= i;
        }
        return fact;
    };

    Function<Integer, Long> memoziedFactorialFunction = memoise(factorialFunction);

    System.out.println(memoziedFactorialFunction.apply(5));
    System.out.println(memoziedFactorialFunction.apply(5));
    System.out.println(memoziedFactorialFunction.apply(5));
    System.out.println(memoziedFactorialFunction.apply(5));
    System.out.println(memoziedFactorialFunction.apply(6));
    System.out.println(memoziedFactorialFunction.apply(6));

}

public static <X, Y> Function<X, Y> memoise(Function<X, Y> fn) {
    Map<X, Y> pp = new ConcurrentHashMap<X, Y>();
    return (a) -> pp.computeIfAbsent(a, fn);
}
```

}

Result is :

```
Calculating factorial for 5
120
120
120
120
Calculating factorial for 6
720
720
```

More details here http://rdafbn.blogspot.ie/2015/06/memoize-functions-in-java-8.html

Lastly, you can use the [cyclops](https://github.com/aol/cyclops) library to remove the boilerplate code of creating memoize generic methods( have a look at http://static.javadoc.io/com.aol.cyclops/cyclops-functions/4.0.2/com/aol/cyclops/functions/Memoise.html)

Answer (score 2):

Check out Guava's [cache](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/Cache.html) package. This is what it is for.

Comment: Memoization would be a great thing if the compiler or the runtime could do it for us. And if the compiler/runtime could safely assume zero side effect methods it would be a reality, nope? See http://tshrestha.blogspot.com/2013/04/scala-and-price-of-not-being-purely.html

Comment: Just in case your in an environment that prevents using a third-party package, here's an implementation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77384428/501113

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a generic map from `<short, ulong>` in Java because generic type parameters only bind to reference types.  You would have to make it `<Short, Long>` which involves wrapping primitives and may introduce some overhead into your memoization.

Besides that, the translation to Java is pretty straight-forward.  Just be aware, you can only memoize types that provide a useful `equals` and `hashCode` implementations, and you need to use a size-bounded, thread-safe, weak-key table such as that provided by [MapMaker](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html).

Comment: Cool what is the Java equiv of C#'s Func type?

Comment: The only additional thought change, is the `Function`. Java doesn't have true functions per the above syntax. You would need to provide an interface that given one type returns another. Guava has this: Function - http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Function.html