# Java memoization method

Tags: java, lambda, memoization

I came across an interesting problem and was wondering if and how could this be done in Java:
Create a method which can memoize any function/method . The method has the following arguments : the method/function and the argument(s) for it.

For example let's say i have this method :

```
int addOne(int a) { return a + 1;}
```

and i call my memoization method two times with the same arguments : addOne and 5 for example, the first call should actually call the addOne method and return the result and also store that result for that given argument. The second time when i call it should know this has been called before and just look up the previous answer.

My idea would be to have something like a `HashMap<Callable,HashMap<List<Objects>,Object>>` where you would store the previous answers and look them up later on.I think this can be somehow done with lambda expressions but i'm not that familiar with them.I'm not quite sure how to write this method and would appreciate some help.

Can this be done with this approach?

Comment: Look into proxying mechanisms with Java. You can create a proxy of an object which intercepts method calls, storing the return value. If you call the method with the same arguments as a previous invocation, you'd get the same result without having to invoke the underlying method. Spring caching does this for you.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In Java 8 you can use [`ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-):

```
Map<Integer, Integer> cache = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

Integer addOne(Integer x) {
    return cache.computeIfAbsent(x -> x + 1);
}
```

DZone has [a good tutorial](https://dzone.com/articles/java-8-automatic-memoization) which provides a solution that will work for any method:

> The `Memoizer` class is quite simple:
>
> ```java
> public class Memoizer<T, U> {
>
>   private final Map<T, U> cache = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
>
>   private Memoizer() {}
>
>   private Function<T, U> doMemoize(final Function<T, U> function) {
>     return input -> cache.computeIfAbsent(input, function::apply);
>   }
>
>   public static <T, U> Function<T, U> memoize(final Function<T, U> function) {
>     return new Memoizer<T, U>().doMemoize(function);
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> Using this class is also extremely simple:
>
> ```java
> Integer longCalculation(Integer x) {
>   try {
>     Thread.sleep(1_000);
>   } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
>   }
>   return x * 2;
> }
> Function<Integer, Integer> f = this::longCalculation;
> Function<Integer, Integer> g = Memoizer.memoize(f);
>
> public void automaticMemoizationExample() {
>   long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
>   Integer result1 = g.apply(1);
>   long time1 = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
>   startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
>   Integer result2 = g.apply(1);
>   long time2 = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
>   System.out.println(result1);
>   System.out.println(result2);
>   System.out.println(time1);
>   System.out.println(time2);
> }
> ```
>
> Running the `automaticMemoizationExample` method will produce the following result:
>
> ```
> 2
> 2
> 1000
> 0
> ```

Comment: Although that is a nice snippet it doesn't answer the OPs question which was how to memoize *any* function

Comment: @MrWiggles You didn't read the link, right? I edited my post so that it is clearer.

Comment: You're right, I didn't, thanks for clarifying, I've removed the -1

Comment: `computeIfAbsent(key, function::apply)` is functionally equivalent to just using function as `computeIfAbsent(key, function)`. Except latter creates one less lambda instance.

Comment: The first example must be `Integer addOne(Integer n) {
    return cache.computeIfAbsent(n, x -> x + 1);
}`

Comment: Thanks. Link is broken but it appears to have moved to https://dzone.com/articles/java-8-automatic-memoization

Comment: This doesn't work for recursive functions. You'll get a `ConcurrentModificationException` if `computeIfAbsent` recursively calls `computeIfAbsent` on the same map.

Answer (score 8):

You can memoize any function with Java 8's `MethodHandle`s and lambdas if you're willing to give up type safety on the parameters:

```
public interface MemoizedFunction<V> {
    V call(Object... args);
}

private static class ArgList {
    public Object[] args;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(o instanceof ArgList)) {
            return false;
        }

        ArgList argList = (ArgList) o;

        // Probably incorrect - comparing Object[] arrays with Arrays.equals
        return Arrays.equals(args, argList.args);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return args != null ? Arrays.hashCode(args) : 0;
    }
}

public static <V> MemoizedFunction<V> memoizeFunction(Class<? super V> returnType, Method method) throws
                                                                                                  IllegalAccessException {
    final Map<ArgList, V> memoizedCalls = new HashMap<>();
    MethodHandles.Lookup lookup = MethodHandles.lookup();
    MethodHandle methodHandle = lookup.unreflect(method)
                                      .asSpreader(Object[].class, method.getParameterCount());
    return args -> {
        ArgList argList = new ArgList();
        argList.args = args;
        return memoizedCalls.computeIfAbsent(argList, argList2 -> {
            try {
                //noinspection unchecked
                return (V) methodHandle.invoke(args);
            } catch (Throwable throwable) {
                throw new RuntimeException(throwable);
            }
        });
    };
}
```

[Working Example](http://pastebin.com/ZgcXnRtG)

This creates a variable-arity lambda that encloses the function and is almost as fast as calling the function directly (i.e., no reflection happens inside of `call(Object...args)`) after the lambda is constructed since we're using `MethodHandle.invoke()` instead of `Method.invoke()`.

You can still do this without lambdas (replace with anonymous classes) and MethodHandles (replace with Method.invoke), but there will be performance penalties that make this less attractive for performance-conscious code.

Comment: Nice one! Was there some plan to use the returnType argument which is currently unused?

Comment: I think it was meant to be used to validate the return type of the `Method`, and was simply forgot.

Comment: @DarthAndroid, shouldn't return type be bound as `? extends V` instead? If method actually returns something that is `? super V`, then it's not really an `args -> V` lambda, and casting returned value like that is not safe.

Comment: It's a trade-off with generics. If we don't `? super`, then `V` is at most a raw type (Because `Class<List<String>>`, for example, is unfortunately not a thing in java), so the caller can't specify the actual return type of `method` in a way the compiler can understand. All we can do is tighten `V` down to its raw type, but that still loses type safety with generic return types. No matter what you do, the compiler won't be able to enforce type safety for generic return types, and if we don't use the `? super V` bit, it'll throw warnings about using raw types even when all the types are correct

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:** For an enhanced and fully documented version of the Memoizer class shown below (including `lazyInstantiation()` static helper method), please visit this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/chaotic3quilibrium/7535c231bb11bd9abc5712c982c46690).

---

While you asked for a specific *method* to accomplish your task, there is an OOP+FP (Object Oriented Programming integrated with Functional Programming) approach to solving the problem. And while I have simplified it below, it enables multiple ways to "generically implement memoize".

I have found it especially useful in my projects. For example, I have exploited it by generating "caching" helpers around various `enum`s. For example, to easily enable finding an `enum` value by a `String` while ignoring case. Another example is to easily enable finding an `enum` value by its `.ordinal()` or database ID.

Here is a list of benefits to a client when contrasted with other solutions I have seen suggested:

1. Null restriction enforced for both keys and values
2. Assumes keys are [effectively immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75043881/501113) (see "Distinction 3")
3. At construction, optionally specify a default lambda for deriving a value from a key
4. At construction, optionally ensures insertion order within `keySet().iterator()` (quite nice for debugging sessions)
5. When accessing, optionally specify an overriding lambda for deriving a value from a key

```java
public final class Memoizer<K, V> {

  private final Map<K, V> vByK;

  private final Optional<Function<K, V>> optionalDefaultDeriveVFromK;

  public static <K, V> Memoizer<K, V> from() {
    return from(false);
  }

  public static <K, V> Memoizer<K, V> from(
      Function<K, V> defaultDeriveVFromK
  ) {
    return from(defaultDeriveVFromK, false);
  }

  public static <K, V> Memoizer<K, V> from(
      boolean isRetainingInsertionOrder
  ) {
    return new Memoizer<>(Optional.empty(), isRetainingInsertionOrder);
  }

  public static <K, V> Memoizer<K, V> from(
      Function<K, V> defaultDeriveVFromK,
      boolean isRetainingInsertionOrder
  ) {
    return new Memoizer<>(Optional.of(Objects.requireNonNull(defaultDeriveVFromK)), isRetainingInsertionOrder);
  }
  
  private Memoizer(
      Optional<Function<K, V>> optionalDefaultDeriveVFromK,
      boolean isRetainingInsertionOrder
  ) {
    this.vByK = isRetainingInsertionOrder
        ? new LinkedHashMap<>()
        : new HashMap<>();
    this.optionalDefaultDeriveVFromK = optionalDefaultDeriveVFromK;
  }

  private V get(
      K k,
      Optional<Function<K, V>> optionalOverrideDeriveVFromK
  ) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(vByK.get(Objects.requireNonNull(k, "k must not be null")))
        .orElseGet(() -> {
          synchronized (vByK) {
            return Optional.ofNullable(vByK.get(k))
                .orElseGet(() -> {
                  var lambda = optionalOverrideDeriveVFromK
                      .or(() -> optionalDefaultDeriveVFromK)
                      .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException(
                          "when optionalDefaultDeriveVFromK is empty, optionalOverrideDeriveVFromK must not be empty"));
                  var v = Objects.requireNonNull(lambda.apply(k),
                      "v returned from %s function must not be null".formatted(
                          optionalOverrideDeriveVFromK.isEmpty()
                              ? "optionalDefaultDeriveVFromK"
                              : "optionalOverrideDeriveVFromK"));
                  vByK.put(k, v);

                  return v;
                });
          }
        });
  }

  public V get(
      K k,
      Function<K, V> overrideDeriveVFromK
  ) {
    return get(k, Optional.of(overrideDeriveVFromK));
  }

  public V get(K k) {
    return get(k, Optional.empty());
  }

  public Set<K> keySet() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableSet(vByK.keySet());
  }
}
```

---

**NOTE:** For an enhanced and fully documented version of the Memoizer class shown below (including `lazyInstantiation()` static helper method), please visit this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/chaotic3quilibrium/7535c231bb11bd9abc5712c982c46690).