# Since Java 9 HashMap.computeIfAbsent() throws ConcurrentModificationException on attempt to memoize recursive function results

Tags: java, recursion, java-9, concurrenthashmap

Today I learned from some JS course what memoization is and tried to implement it in Java. I had a simple recursive function to evaluate n-th Fibonacci number:

```
long fib(long n) {
    if (n < 2) {
        return n;
    }

    return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
}
```

Then I decided to use HashMap in order to cache results of recursive method:

```
private static <I, O> Function<I, O> memoize(Function<I, O> fn) {
    final Map<I, O> cache = new HashMap<>();
    return in -> {
        if (cache.get(in) != null) {
            return cache.get(in);
        } else {
            O result = fn.apply(in);
            cache.put(in, result);
            return result;
        }
    };
}
```

This worked as I expected and it allowed me to memoize `fib()` like this `memoize(this::fib)`

Then I googled the subject of memoization in Java and found the question: [Java memoization method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27549864/java-memoization-method) where `computeIfAbsent` was proposed which is much shorter than my conditional expression.

So my final code which I expected to work was:

```
public class FibMemo {
    private final Function<Long, Long> memoizedFib = memoize(this::slowFib);

    public long fib(long n) {
        return memoizedFib.apply(n);
    }

    long slowFib(long n) {
        if (n < 2) {
            return n;
        }

        return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
    }

    private static <I, O> Function<I, O> memoize(Function<I, O> fn) {
        final Map<I, O> cache = new HashMap<>();
        return in -> cache.computeIfAbsent(in, fn);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new FibMemo().fib(50);
    }
}
```

Since I used Java 11, I got:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.computeIfAbsent(HashMap.java:1134)
    at algocasts.matrix.fibonacci.FibMemo.lambda$memoize$0(FibMemo.java:24)
    at algocasts.matrix.fibonacci.FibMemo.fib(FibMemo.java:11)
    at algocasts.matrix.fibonacci.FibMemo.slowFib(FibMemo.java:19)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.computeIfAbsent(HashMap.java:1133)
    at algocasts.matrix.fibonacci.FibMemo.lambda$memoize$0(FibMemo.java:24)
```

The problem quickly brought me to the following question which is very similar: [Recursive ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent() call never terminates. Bug or "feature"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28840047/recursive-concurrenthashmap-computeifabsent-call-never-terminates-bug-or-fea)

except Lukas used ConcurrentHashMap and got never ending loop. In the article related to the question Lukas advised:

> The simplest use-site solution for this concrete problem would be to not use a ConcurrentHashMap, but just a HashMap instead:

`static Map<Integer, Integer> cache = new HashMap<>();`

That's exactly what I was trying to do, but did not succeed with Java 11. I found out empirically that HashMap throws ConcurrentModificationException since Java 9 (thanks SDKMAN):

```
sdk use java 9.0.7-zulu && javac Test.java && java Test # throws ConcurrentModificationException
sdk use java 8.0.202-zulufx && javac Test.java && java Test # works as expected
```

Here are the summary of my attempts:

- Java 8 && ConcurrentHashMap -> works if input < 13, otherwise endless
  loop
- Java 9 && ConcurrentHashMap -> works if input < 13, hangs if
  input = 14, throws `IllegalStateException: Recursive update` if input
  is 50
- Java 8 && HashMap -> Works!
- Java 9 && HashMap -> Throws
  `ConcurrentModificationException` after input >= 3

I would like to know why ConcurrentModificationException gets thrown on attempt to use HashMap as a cache for recursive function? Was it a bug in Java 8 allowing me to do so or is it another in Java > 9 which throws ConcurrentModificationException?

Comment: This is clearly [documented](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashMap.html#computeIfAbsent(K,java.util.function.Function)) for Java 11 HashMap: "The mapping function should not modify this map during computation." This wording is missing from the Java 8 documentation.

Comment: The [bug in Java-8](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8062841) related to the endless loop has been reported and fixed in Java-9.

Comment: @nullpointer different bug, if you annotate the JDK code the commit leads to JDK-8071667

Comment: @KarolDowbecki I believe, we are both addressing two different issues there.

Comment: I (randomly) get `ConcurrentModificationException` without modifying the map in the `computeIfAbsent` func. Can it happen with simple concurrent access on the `HashMap`? (my threads never access the same keys). Edit - yep I need `ConcurrentHashMap`... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688629/is-a-hashmap-thread-safe-for-different-keys

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`ConcurrentModificationException` is thrown because `slowFib` is modifying multiple keys and values. If you look at [Java 9 `HashMap.computeIfAbsent()` code](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/jdk/file/65464a307408/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java#l1136) you will find that the exception is thrown here:

```
int mc = modCount;
V v = mappingFunction.apply(key);
if (mc != modCount) { throw new ConcurrentModificationException(); }
```

Each invocation of `slowFib` attempts to modify values mapped to keys `n-1` and `n-2`.

The `modCount` check is not performed in Java 8 `HashMap.computeIfAbsent()` code. This is a bug in Java 8, your approach doesn't work in all cases as per [JDK-8071667 HashMap.computeIfAbsent() adds entry that HashMap.get() does not find](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8071667) which added the `modCount` check in Java 9:

> If the function supplied to computeIfAbsent adds items to the same HashTable on which the function is called from and the internal table is enlarged because of this, the new entry will be added to the wrong place in the Map's internal table making it inaccessible.

Comment: That’s especially a documentation flaw, as it doesn’t tell that the functions are not allowed to modify the map. Only the specific implementation class `ConcurrentHashMap` has such a remark in its documentation.

Answer (score 3):

You can roll your own:

```java
public static <K, V> V computeIfAbsent(
    Map<K, V> cache, 
    K key,
    Function<? super K, ? extends V> function
) {
    V result = cache.get(key);

    if (result == null) {
        result = function.apply(key);
        cache.put(key, result);
    }

    return result;
}
```

This approach assumes you don't have `null` values. If you do, just change the logic to use `Map.containsKey()`

This access works around the problem by making the cache value retrieval and putting of calculated values non-atomic again, which `Map::computeIfAbsent` tries to avoid. I.e. the usual race condition problems re-occur. But that might be fine in your case, of course.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ConcurrentSkipListMap`

It is a thread-safe map and it will not through `ConcurrentModificationException` in recursive & itaration of collections while using computeIfAbsent().

Reference:

https://dzone.com/articles/avoid-recursive-invocation-on-computeifabsent-in-h

Answer (score 0):

What about this one? Not sure about performance though...

```
public class Fibonacci {

  private static final Map<Integer, Integer> memoized = new ConcurrentSkipListMap<>(Map.of(1,1,2,1));

  public static int fib(int n) {
    return memoized.computeIfAbsent(n, x -> fib(x - 2) + fib(x - 1));
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(fib(12));
  }

}
```