# When load some class in checkPermission method why SecurityManager emit recursive update exception?

Tags: java, java-11, securitymanager, java-security-manager

I'm upgrading jdk 8 to 11.

I load some class in `checkPermission` method then security manager emit `recursive update` exception. but use `jdk1.8.0_202` everything works fine.

What causes this problem?

1. My environment.

```
OS: macOS 10.15.6
JDK(Oracle): 11.0.8
IDE: Intellij 2019 3
```

2. Main

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world");
    }
}
```

3. SecurityManager

```
package sm;

import java.security.Permission;

public class MySecurityManager extends SecurityManager {

    @Override
    public void checkPermission(Permission permission) {

        // Problem occurs when load ServicePermission.class
        if (permission instanceof javax.security.auth.kerberos.ServicePermission) {
            // throw new SecurityException("javax.security.auth.kerberos.ServicePermission is not allowed.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void checkPermission(Permission permission, Object context) {
        this.checkPermission(permission);
    }
}
```

4. Run with `-Djava.security.manager=sm.MySecurityManager`
5. Console logs

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: bootstrap method initialization exception
    at java.lang.invoke.BootstrapMethodInvoker.invoke(java.base@11.0.8/BootstrapMethodInvoker.java:194)
    at java.lang.invoke.CallSite.makeSite(java.base@11.0.8/CallSite.java:307)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkCallSiteImpl(java.base@11.0.8/MethodHandleNatives.java:258)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkCallSite(java.base@11.0.8/MethodHandleNatives.java:248)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jrt.JavaRuntimeURLConnection.<clinit>(java.base@11.0.8/JavaRuntimeURLConnection.java:55)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jrt.Handler.openConnection(java.base@11.0.8/Handler.java:42)
    at java.net.URL.openConnection(java.base@11.0.8/URL.java:1074)
    at jdk.internal.module.SystemModuleFinders$SystemModuleReader.checkPermissionToConnect(java.base@11.0.8/SystemModuleFinders.java:405)
    at jdk.internal.module.SystemModuleFinders$SystemModuleReader.<init>(java.base@11.0.8/SystemModuleFinders.java:414)
    at jdk.internal.module.SystemModuleFinders$2.get(java.base@11.0.8/SystemModuleFinders.java:315)
    at jdk.internal.module.SystemModuleFinders$2.get(java.base@11.0.8/SystemModuleFinders.java:312)
    at jdk.internal.module.ModuleReferenceImpl.open(java.base@11.0.8/ModuleReferenceImpl.java:93)
    at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader$5.apply(java.base@11.0.8/BuiltinClassLoader.java:961)
    at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader$5.apply(java.base@11.0.8/BuiltinClassLoader.java:958)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(java.base@11.0.8/ConcurrentHashMap.java:1705)
    at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.moduleReaderFor(java.base@11.0.8/BuiltinClassLoader.java:969)
    at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(java.base@11.0.8/BuiltinClassLoader.java:731)
    at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.lambda$findClassInModuleOrNull$2(java.base@11.0.8/BuiltinClassLoader.java:682)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(java.base@11.0.8/Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassInModuleOrNull(java.base@11.0.8/BuiltinClassLoader.java:683)
    at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(java.base@11.0.8/BuiltinClassLoader.java:605)
    at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(java.base@11.0.8/BuiltinClassLoader.java:640)
    at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(java.base@11.0.8/BuiltinClassLoader.java:609)
    at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(java.base@11.0.8/BuiltinClassLoader.java:579)
    at jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(java.base@11.0.8/ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.base@11.0.8/ClassLoader.java:521)
    at sm.MySecurityManager.checkPermission(MySecurityManager.java:11)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPropertyAccess(java.base@11.0.8/SecurityManager.java:1066)
    at java.lang.System.getProperty(java.base@11.0.8/System.java:814)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.initSystemClassLoader(java.base@11.0.8/ClassLoader.java:1971)
    at java.lang.System.initPhase3(java.base@11.0.8/System.java:2070)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Recursive update
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(java.base@11.0.8/ConcurrentHashMap.java:1760)
    at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.moduleReaderFor(java.base@11.0.8/BuiltinClassLoader.java:969)
    at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(java.base@11.0.8/BuiltinClassLoader.java:731)
    at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.lambda$findClassInModuleOrNull$2(java.base@11.0.8/BuiltinClassLoader.java:682)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(java.base@11.0.8/Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassInModuleOrNull(java.base@11.0.8/BuiltinClassLoader.java:683)
    at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(java.base@11.0.8/BuiltinClassLoader.java:605)
    at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(java.base@11.0.8/BuiltinClassLoader.java:640)
    at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(java.base@11.0.8/BuiltinClassLoader.java:609)
    at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(java.base@11.0.8/BuiltinClassLoader.java:579)
    at jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(java.base@11.0.8/ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.base@11.0.8/ClassLoader.java:521)
    at sm.MySecurityManager.checkPermission(MySecurityManager.java:11)
    at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkPermission(java.base@11.0.8/AccessibleObject.java:83)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.setAccessible(java.base@11.0.8/Constructor.java:180)
    at java.lang.invoke.InnerClassLambdaMetafactory$1.run(java.base@11.0.8/InnerClassLambdaMetafactory.java:206)
    at java.lang.invoke.InnerClassLambdaMetafactory$1.run(java.base@11.0.8/InnerClassLambdaMetafactory.java:199)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(java.base@11.0.8/Native Method)
    at java.lang.invoke.InnerClassLambdaMetafactory.buildCallSite(java.base@11.0.8/InnerClassLambdaMetafactory.java:198)
    at java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(java.base@11.0.8/LambdaMetafactory.java:329)
    at java.lang.invoke.BootstrapMethodInvoker.invoke(java.base@11.0.8/BootstrapMethodInvoker.java:127)
    at java.lang.invoke.CallSite.makeSite(java.base@11.0.8/CallSite.java:307)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkCallSiteImpl(java.base@11.0.8/MethodHandleNatives.java:258)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkCallSite(java.base@11.0.8/MethodHandleNatives.java:248)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jrt.JavaRuntimeURLConnection.<clinit>(java.base@11.0.8/JavaRuntimeURLConnection.java:55)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jrt.Handler.openConnection(java.base@11.0.8/Handler.java:42)
    at java.net.URL.openConnection(java.base@11.0.8/URL.java:1074)
    at jdk.internal.module.SystemModuleFinders$SystemModuleReader.checkPermissionToConnect(java.base@11.0.8/SystemModuleFinders.java:405)
    at jdk.internal.module.SystemModuleFinders$SystemModuleReader.<init>(java.base@11.0.8/SystemModuleFinders.java:414)
    at jdk.internal.module.SystemModuleFinders$2.get(java.base@11.0.8/SystemModuleFinders.java:315)
    at jdk.internal.module.SystemModuleFinders$2.get(java.base@11.0.8/SystemModuleFinders.java:312)
    at jdk.internal.module.ModuleReferenceImpl.open(java.base@11.0.8/ModuleReferenceImpl.java:93)
    at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader$5.apply(java.base@11.0.8/BuiltinClassLoader.java:961)
    at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader$5.apply(java.base@11.0.8/BuiltinClassLoader.java:958)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(java.base@11.0.8/ConcurrentHashMap.java:1705)
    at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.moduleReaderFor(java.base@11.0.8/BuiltinClassLoader.java:969)
    at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(java.base@11.0.8/BuiltinClassLoader.java:731)
    at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.lambda$findClassInModuleOrNull$2(java.base@11.0.8/BuiltinClassLoader.java:682)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(java.base@11.0.8/Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassInModuleOrNull(java.base@11.0.8/BuiltinClassLoader.java:683)
    at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(java.base@11.0.8/BuiltinClassLoader.java:605)
    at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(java.base@11.0.8/BuiltinClassLoader.java:640)
    at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(java.base@11.0.8/BuiltinClassLoader.java:609)
    at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(java.base@11.0.8/BuiltinClassLoader.java:579)
    at jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(java.base@11.0.8/ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.base@11.0.8/ClassLoader.java:521)
    at sm.MySecurityManager.checkPermission(MySecurityManager.java:11)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPropertyAccess(java.base@11.0.8/SecurityManager.java:1066)
    at java.lang.System.getProperty(java.base@11.0.8/System.java:814)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.initSystemClassLoader(java.base@11.0.8/ClassLoader.java:1971)
    at java.lang.System.initPhase3(java.base@11.0.8/System.java:2070)


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: The easy "fix" would be to add a constructor that loads the necessary classes - or just calls `checkPermission` itself: `public MySecurityManager() { checkPermission(new AllPermission()); }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The stack trace indicates that the issue is connected with the *module loading* rather than class loading, which explains why you don’t have the problem in JDK 8 that doesn’t have modules.

When you read the stack trace starting at the bottom, i.e.

```
    at java.lang.System.initPhase3(java.base@11.0.8/System.java:2070)
```

you will encounter the stack frames

```
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(java.base@11.0.8/ConcurrentHashMap.java:1705)
    at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.moduleReaderFor(java.base@11.0.8/BuiltinClassLoader.java:969)
```

indicating an attempt to load a module. This will eventually end up at a privileged action that needs a check, so you’ll find the line

```
    at sm.MySecurityManager.checkPermission(MySecurityManager.java:11)
```

which triggers the loading of `javax.security.auth.kerberos.ServicePermission` which is in the module `java.security.jgss` which apparently has not been loaded before.

So the `loadClass` call ends up again at

```
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(java.base@11.0.8/ConcurrentHashMap.java:1760)
    at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.moduleReaderFor(java.base@11.0.8/BuiltinClassLoader.java:969)
```

which triggers the “java.lang.IllegalStateException: Recursive update”, as calling `computeIfAbsent` is not allowed from another `computeIfAbsent` call on the same `ConcurrentHashMap`. Since ignoring this constraint can lead to corrupted maps, a check has been added in Java 9 to reject such attempts. See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54824656/2711488).

---

Generally, triggering class loading from a security manager that might get checked again during the class loading can be problematic. I suggest resorting to the [documented `toString()` output](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/Permission.html#toString--) for comparison. After all, that’s what the policy file based security implementation does as well.

Since [`ServicePermission`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/security/auth/kerberos/ServicePermission.html) is `final`, a cheaper `permission.getClass().getName().equals( "javax.security.auth.kerberos.ServicePermission")` would do as well. Both approaches avoid loading the permission if it has not been used before. As indicated by the issue, this may even save the loading of an entire module.